# Change background color win32

Tags: c++, windows

i've been training in the win32 api in c++ I have made a window, a button, and a text box but this is what i had:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCEwK.png

but there is a text box right there::

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhJl.png

not so clear, is it? now what exactly I want to do is I want to color either the window's or the text box's background color so it become more obvious

thanks guys.....

Answer (score 0):

ok no one answered the question and I had to look it up my self....

I added a property WM_BORDER which added a border around the text box so it became clear, hope it helps.